# How to get the Ipad and Iphones viewport width using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get the correct width of the viewport of an Ipad and Iphone using jquery. 
Because my webpage is larger than the Ipad's native size it gets scaled down. What I'm trying to do is set my content div to be the width of each browser and then set overview hidden. This works in desktop browsers. When I test in Ipad or Iphone its a different story because of the scaling in the IOS. I want to keep that scaling but be able to retrieve the correct width. I have tried both width and outerWidth() but no luck.

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#content').css({width: $(this).outerWidth()});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$( window ).height();
$( window ).width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use percentages in CSS?

For example, you can accomplish the same thing you're doing in your example with the following:

```
#content { width: 100%; }
```

EDIT: Also, if you wish to accomplish different things in different devices, I would suggest that you read about CSS media queries and responsive design.

For example, let's say that in the full view of your website you want your content to occupy the 70% of the width and the sidebar to occupy the rest. But, when someone views your website from a smartphone, you want the content to occupy the full width of the page and the sidebar to go underneath it, with a full width as well. You can do it like that:

```
.main-content { width: 70%; float: left; }
.sidebar { width: 30%; float: left;}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .main-content, .sidebar { width: 100%; }
}
```